# Get only a unique value on dates of an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have trouble for what I thought will be a simple task...
I need to remove the duplicate value of my array for example there are 3 times 2018-02-20 13:48:44 and I only want 1 of those value.

```
MyTab = [#<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 13:47:15">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 13:48:44">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 13:48:44">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 13:48:44">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:25:14">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:25:14">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:25:14">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:32:38">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:36:42">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:36:42">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 14:40:16">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 15:30:15">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-02-20 15:30:15">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-03-06 10:24:25">, #<Poll id: nil, created_at: "2018-03-06 10:24:25">]
```

I already tried this but it does not work :

```
MyTab.uniq{|x| x.created_at}
```

Thanks for answers :).

Z.

Comment: I can't see any reason your original code wouldn't work. Are you aware that `uniq` returns a new array, and doesn't modify the original array? Use `uniq!` if you want to modify the original.

Comment: There's no `uniq` method for ActiveRecord::QueryMethods in Rails 5. [Deprecated in favor of distinct](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/adfab2dcf4003ca564d78d4425566dd2d9cd8b4f).

Comment: Given that `created_at` by default is a timestamp, are you sure this is really what you need? It is highly unlikely that you created two records in exactly the same millisecond.

Comment: Yes, that array is what i got when i submit my form. 
And i need to make sure the number of people that answered my form is different of the number of response for that question...

Comment: @Sox-, what does that have to do with uniqueness by `created_at`?

Comment: Well, to differentiate the 2 things i talked about it I chose to do it using created_at because when that person will submit the form no-one else will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : Ok i think i get why it 's not working if i try with

a = [["first"], ["second"], ["first"]].uniq
It is working, so i ll change to have my array this way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably slower; but should work :

`MyTab.uniq { |x| Time.parse(x.created_at).to_i }`

Comment: It does for sure; i would not have answered otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If you can rewrite your query directly from the model i would suggest to do the logic directly in it.

```
Poll.select(:created_at).where("#{query_conditions}").distinct
```

If not I suggest @ben's answer.

Comment: I'll give a try if I can't do it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

find_by_sql ["SELECT DISTINCT created_at,  FROM your_table_name "]
or 
MyTab.flatten!
Note- this will orerwrite MyTab array with unique values